# Should we use Router in Effects

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

I'm trying to route to another page within an Effect and I get the following error, I was wondering if I can use Router inside effects anyway.

> Effect "NavigateToPageEffects.updatePageId$" dispatched an invalid action

```
    @Injectable()
export class NavigateToWorkflowEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

     @Effect()
      updatePageId$ = this.actions$
        .ofType(NAVIGATE_TO_PAGE)
        .map((action: Action) => (action as NavigateToPageAction).payload)
        .map((page: PageViewModel) =>
          this.router.navigate([RoutePaths.page, page.id]));
```

The reason I'm navigating through effect is that I need to another action to happen first then to navigate.
My initial code looked like below inside my component but I got the order of execution issue:

```
  savedClicked(page: PageViewModel) {
    this.store.dispatch(new NavigateToPageAction(page));
     this.router.navigate([RoutePaths.page, page.id]);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Please see if this article can help you. https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/ngrx/ngrx-effects-4-example.

Comment: @Rohit.007 Thanks a lot for the link,  `@Effect({ dispatch: false })` did the job for me!